# Output variable by combining the variable's names

Tags: php

I have the following in a for loop over `$x.  $x` is from *1 to 100*.  I have variables `t1` to `t100` already assigned.  I want to echo them without typing each one individually, hence the for loop,  but the following does not work:

```
echo "<br>'$t.$x'";
```

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to combine the variable names:

```
echo ${"t".$x};
```

but this reeks of imperfect design. Why not use an array instead?

Comment: Not sure how to use an array for it :(  Each echo requires 2 consecutive t's, like t1 and t2 are together, t3 and t4 etc.

Comment: @David you can run through an array in steps of two: `for ($i = 0; $i <= count($array); $i+=2 }`

Comment: I have this now //echo "<a href=".${'t'.$x}.">".${'t'.$y}".</a><br>";

Comment: @David19801 looks like something I would use an array of objects for.

Comment: @David19801 it's still job for array and nothing else. Don't be ignorant, learn proper way

Answer (score 0):

```
$varname = 't'.$x;
echo $$varname;
```

Comment: Anyone wondering about the downvotes: the usual suspects strike again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
$name = 't' . $x;
echo $$name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for($x=1;$x<=100;$x++) {
        echo '<br>'.${'t'.$x};
}
```